# Javascript Function Doesn’t Execute

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, display

This simple function doesn’t execute when called. When taken out of the function it runs but not in the function. What gets the function to run?

HTML

```
<img id = “hide” src = “mypic.jpg”>
```

Javascript

```
Function show {
var x = document.getElementById(“hide”);
x.style.display = “none”
}

show();
```

Comment: Hi @Dre, I've rolled back your edit to the question as your change removes the cause of the issue you were seeing. If it's the case that you're *still* seeing an issue, you'll probably need to add more detail in order for the question to be re-opened/taken off hold =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong declaration for a function

```
Function show {
var x = document.getElementById(“hide”);
x.style.display = “none”
}

show();
```

should be written as:

```js
function show() {
  var x = document.getElementById('hide');
  x.style.display = 'none';
}

show();
```

```html
<img id ="hide" src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of minor issues in your javascript, it should look like:

```
function show() {
  var x = document.getElementById(“hide”);
  x.style.display = “none”;
}

show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code some basics are missing

1. "Function" must be "function"
2. function name must be with parenthesis i.e. functionName(){};

Your function declaration must be like this 
  function show(){}

Then you have to call the same function on some event like onClick() etc.

Here is the link you can go through  [JAVASCRIPT](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Hope this helps you...Cheers!